# Should edits to un-salvageable off-topic questions be accepted?

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

so looking at the suggested edit review i came across [this one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/33064). the question is an id request and in this case the OP made the question while unregistered and then created a new account when they went to edit.

now because we don't accept id request aside from a limited sub selection (the anime series must be known) the edit is kinda pointless since in the end the question will be closed and deleted.

from my understanding edits are supposed to improve content but since id requests are for the most part un-salvageable should we accept suggested edits to un-salvageable questions?

NOTE: the linked edit was approved while i was making this but the question still applies

Comment: Will the edit prevent the closure? No? No improvement whatsoever

Answer (score 8):

In case of ID requests, I don't think it really matters either way. Just don't forget to cast your close and delete votes, because that's what's important.

Comment: Concur. In the grand scheme of things, it doesn't matter what you do with suggested edits on questions that are on their way to closure/deletion.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, the SE guideline is to accept edits if they are not spam or vandalism, attempts to reply, superfluous, decreasing the post’s quality, etc. Basically all the reasons you see in the box to reject edits. Implicitly, if edits *do* improve the quality of a post, do not conflict with the author’s intent, etc., they should be allowed.

However, as you stated, there is absolutely no reason to edit that post. And this is because:

- the question is undesirable and the edit doesn’t (cannot) salvage it
- the edit would bump the question on the front page and give it uncalled visibility

Furthermore, OP should have either registered an account or made sure they kept their cookie around to prevent having to go through the review queue — it *is* supposed to be their own post. Even though the edit would be pointless if they were still associated with the posting account, it at least wouldn’t have wasted anybody’s time in the review queue.

All in all, there is no harm in rejecting that edit. Probably with the custom reject reason; likely something like

> Don’t polish turds
>
> The post is unsalvageably off-topic, the edit is pointless

or something similar.